# Issues With ZIndex using reactjs and a fixed navbar

Tags: css, reactjs

I have read through many posts/information about Z index and still have not been able to figure this out, I have a website with the navbar position fixed so it stays on the top of the page on scroll, when I get down below my header (component where the navbar is placed), all the elements appear ABOVE the navbar when scrolled over (which is obviously not desired), I am able to put a zIndex of -1 on those elements to fix this, however currently I have a form, and making its zIndex -1 makes all the form inputs and submit button disabled or unclickable (guessing it puts the form below another div/element), so I'm pretty stuck and appreciate any advice .. :)

Navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Radium from "radium";
class NavBar extends Component {
  state = {
    topOfPage: true,
    headerSection: true
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.navBarState);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.navBarState);
  }

  navBarState = () => {
    if (window.scrollY < 58) {
      this.setState({
        topOfPage: true
      });
    }
    if (window.scrollY > 58 && window.scrollY < 740) {
      this.setState({
        topOfPage: false,
        headerSection: true
      });
    }
    if (window.scrollY > 740) {
      this.setState({
        headerSection: false
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { topOfPage, headerSection } = this.state;
    let navStyle;
    let linkStyle;
    if (topOfPage && headerSection) {
      navStyle = {
        base: {
          background: "transparent",
          transition: "background-color 0.7s ease"
        }
      };
      linkStyle = {
        base: {
          transition: "font-size 0.8s",
          ":hover": {
            color: "black",
            fontSize: "25px",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            background: "white",
            textTransform: "uppercase",
            paddingTop: "10px",
            borderRadius: "50px"
          }
        }
      };
    } else if (!topOfPage && headerSection) {
      navStyle = {
        base: {
          background: "rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.87)",
          boxShadow: "0 8px 6px -6px",
          transition: "background-color 0.7s ease"
        }
      };
      linkStyle = {
        base: {
          transition: "font-size 0.5s",
          ":hover": {
            color: "white",
            fontSize: "25px",
            fontWeight: "bold"
          }
        }
      };
    } else {
      navStyle = {
        base: {
          background: "rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.99)",
          boxShadow: "0 8px 6px -6px"
        }
      };
      linkStyle = {
        base: {
          transition: "font-size 0.5s",
          ":hover": {
            color: "white",
            fontSize: "25px",
            fontWeight: "bold"
          }
        }
      };
    }
    return (
      <nav style={[navStyle.base]}>
        <ul className="navbarWrapper">
          <li>
            <a href="#!" style={[linkStyle.base]} key="1">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" style={[linkStyle.base]} key="2">
              Beat Store
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" style={[linkStyle.base]} key="3">
              Licensing
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" style={[linkStyle.base]} key="4">
              Drum Kits
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" style={[linkStyle.base]} key="5">
              Contact Us
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Radium(NavBar);
```

Form.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Button, Grid, Segment, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

const FreeBeatForm = () => {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      style={{
        marginTop: "50px",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",

      }}
    >
      <Grid.Column width={5} style={{zIndex: '-1'}}>
        <Segment>
          <h1>Subscribe</h1>
          <Form>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Name</label>
              <Input placeholder="Name" />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Email</label>
              <Input placeholder="Email" />
            </Form.Field>
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </Form>
        </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default FreeBeatForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave out the z-index for your components in the page, instead make sure your `NavBar` as `position:fixed` and it has a higher `z-index`, for example you could use 1000.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. I've tried that as well using both inline styling and external css with no luck..

Comment: please make a reproducible piece of code we can have a look in more details

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has something to do with the semantic ui components, because changing my semantic Inputs to bootstrap inputs fixed the issue..

Comment: For additional context, my Navbar was placed inside of a showcase component/div, adding the z-index of 999 and position relative to the showcase div, which is the **parent** of the NavBar, fixes the issue completely, and even now works with semantic ui components